# Set parameters for Ubuntu's alias

Tags: command-line, bashrc, alias, g++, zsh

I have an example command as follows:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -I/usr/local/include/opencv4
```

Running the entire above command will create file `main` based on the second argument `main` after the parameter `-o`. I have reset it in file `.zshrc` as follows:

```
alias ocv='f(){ g++ "$@" -o built_$@ -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -I/usr/local/include/opencv4; unset -f f; }; f'
```

Now run the above command as follows:

```
ocv main.cpp
```

It will create a file called `built_main.cpp`. But I want it to generate the file `main` by removing the extension `.cpp`. How to do it?

Comment: Why an alias that invokes a self-deleting function instead of a full function? You could even autoload it in zsh, were it a function, in addition to having more “room” for more complex tasks. Though, for this particular case I would actually recommend some kind of build tool, such as make.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For zsh you should use modifier `:r` on `$@`, see e.g. [this](https://zaiste.net/posts/zsh-get-filename-extension-path/).

So it would be

```
alias ocv='f(){ g++ "$@" -o built_$@:r -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -I/usr/local/include/opencv4; unset -f f; }; f'
```